# Why does pip throw WinError 225 on moosegesture installing?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm trying to install moosegesture, using pip install moosegesture in PyCharm and I get this error:

> ERROR: Error [WinError 225] The operation failed because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info

[image]

So far using pip worked fine for me.

Can I install it some other way or what can I do with this error?